# ModelState Not Valid for Blank Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with a dropdownlist with a blank selection. I want the user to be able to enter a blank selection if they want. But, the model state comes back as invalid for the CountryID. Any help will be appreciated.

Create.cshtml:

```
@(Html.DropDownList("CountryID", Model.Countries, ""))
```

Office.cs:

```
public class Office
{
    public Office()
    {
    }

    public Office(Int32 SyncID, string OfficeName)
    {
        this.SyncID = SyncID;
        this.OfficeName = OfficeName;
    }

    public Int32 OfficeID { get; set; }
    public Int32 SyncID { get; set; }
    public Int32 OfficeRollupID { get; set; }
    public Int32 StateProvID { get; set; }
    public Int32 CountryID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Office Name")]
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Office Rollup")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OfficeRollups { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State/Province")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateProvinces { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

    public List<SquareFootage> SquareFootages { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Office model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //db.SaveChanges();

    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Where is the `CountryID` property?

Comment: You have only 1 property in your office model ?

Comment: I added the CountryID property, thanks for the comments.

Comment: Is that your whole model class? There are no other properties on there with validation annotations?

Comment: I added the whole Office class.

Comment: Maybe my Country ID should be a nullable integer?

Comment: Are you filling `OfficeName ` property? That is **Required**

Comment: Yes. Office Name is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the countryId nullable

```
public int? CountryID { get; set; }
```